# Trying to get meta tags using CURL request in PHP without using Dom Document class?

Tags: php, html, curl, meta-tags

I am trying to get certain meta tag from an URL using curl request in PHP and without using Dom Document Class. Till now i am able to get the url html in a variable using curl request but now without parsing dom document how can i get a certain meta tag value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason for avoiding Dom?

Comment: No reason it's a test but i am not able to find any solution without using Dom class at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below code to get the content part of the meta tag,

$_regex = '/

preg_match($_regex, YOUR_HTML_CONTENT, $output);

print_r($output);

Comment: Formatted the code, but the syntax still makes little sense (see highlighting). Please fix these errors.